# Applying indexers on a class inheriting from a collection C#

Tags: c#

I have a class which inherits from a list of list implementing an indexer

```
public class TwoDList<T>: List<List<T>>
{
  public T this[int row, int column]
        {
            get; 
            set ;
        }
}
```

on newing it and using it like this :

```
 TwoDCollection<int> target = new TwoDCollection<int>();
   var linearSequecValue = target[0, 2];
```

but i get a compile time error " No overload for method 'this' takes 2 argument "

Comment: TwoDList and TwoDCollection? Typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine (assuming you provide the `get` and `set` bodies); is this:

- a typo between `TwoDList<T>` / `TwoDCollection<T>`?
- are you actually typing as `List<T>` / `IList<T>` somewhere?

I should also say: it is usually a bad idea to **inherit** from `List<T>` to provide functionality; *encapsulating* it would be better.

Working example:

```
class Program
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        TwoDList<int> target = new TwoDList<int>();
        var linearSequecValue = target[0, 2];
    }
}

public class TwoDList<T> : List<List<T>>
{
    public T this[int row, int column]
    {
        get { return this[row][column]; }
        set { this[row][column] = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use:

```
TwoDList<int> target = new TwoDList<int>();
var linearSequecValue = target[0, 2];
```

That's my attempt:

```
    public int Test()
    {
        TwoDList<int> target = new TwoDList<int>();
        target.Add(new List<int>(new int[] {3,5,6}));
        target.Add(new List<int>(new int[] {2,1,8}));
        target.Add(new List<int>(new int[] {1,3,4}));
        return target[1, 2];
    }

public class TwoDList<T> : List<List<T>>
{
    public T this[int row, int column]
    {
        get { return this[row][column]; }
        set { this[row][column] = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TwoDList<int> target = new TwoDList<int>(); 
   var linearSequecValue = target[0, 2];
```

you can try this

```
public class TwoDList<T> : List<List<T>> 
{ 
    public T this[int row, int column] 
    { 
         get { return this[row][column]; } 
         set { this[row][column] = value; } 
    } 
}
```

instead of this

```
public class TwoDList<T>: List<List<T>>   
{   
  public T this[int row, int column]   
        {   
            get;    
            set ;   
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TwoDList<T> : List<List<T>>
{
    public T this[int row, int column]
    {
      get { return (this[row])[column]; }
    }
}

TwoDList<int> target = new TwoDList<int>();
var linearSequecValue = target[0, 2];
```

works fine

what's TwoDCollection's definition?

Answer (score 0):

You have your `indexer` in your `derived type` but there should be a `custom implementation in your indexer body` (for, `get; set;`) **because you already have inherited 2 `Lists<>`**.

For Now, **without changing your code**, you can `use like this`:

```
var linearSequecValue = target[0][2];
```

Hope this helps!